# Backend container ip unable to connect to the database mysql using docker

Tags: docker, nestjs, typeorm

my db IP is 172.21.0.2 and backend is 172.21.0.3. I'm noob at docker, can you explain to me why backend container cannot connect to the database? thank you very much.

error message:

[image]

this is my dockerfile:

```
    FROM node:15.4

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package.json . 
    RUN npm install
    COPY . . 

    CMD npm run start:dev
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: '3.9'
    services:
      backend:
        build: .
        ports:
         - 8000:3000
        volumes: 
         - .:/app
        depends_on:
         - db

     db:
      image: mysql:5.7.22
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes: 
         - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
         - 33066:3306
```

and app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
   imports: [UserModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
   type: 'mysql',
   host: 'db',
   port: 3306,
   username: 'root',
   password: 'root',
   database: 'admin',
   autoLoadEntities: true,
   synchronize: true,
  }), AuthModule],
 controllers: [AppController],
 providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, post the text in a code block.

Comment: ok, I already changed it

Comment: Thanks; your first screenshot is also textual data.

Comment: If your database already exists, then the environment variables you set (like MYSQL_USER) aren't used for anything. They're only used if the database doesn't already exist and the startup script has to create it. So if the database already exists and has been created with other parameters, then they may not be what you expect. Try deleting the .dbdata directory to make sure that there's no old data.

Comment: in your appmodule, try chaning host: 'db' to host:'docker.host.internal'
BTW, you expose the db on port 33066, but try to access it with 3306.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out solved by just delete/remove db `volumes: - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql`